# pd.getdummies python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set with 12 columns and one of my column "Devices" has 250 features - Different phone names.

[image]

What I am trying to do is, apply opd.get dummies and create 3 columns - one for Apple devices, 2nd for Samsung and the 3rd for all the other device names.

[image]

Can this be done?

Comment: what did you try? Show your code. What did you get? Did you get errror message? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: first try to do this and later ask question. And if you already tired it then show you code instead of asking if it can be done.

Comment: df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Devices"])

df.head()

Tried the above and it created 27 extra columns

Comment: put code in question - it will more readable. And what wrong with this code? Do you get error message ? Then show it in question. If you get wrong result then show it also in question. Asking `Can this be done?` you only waste time because answer is `yes`. But if you don't know how to do this then at least show in question what did you try.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it then, instead of writing a big speech. As I said in my question, i dont want multiple columns but only 3 columns. since i dont know how to do it, am asking.

Comment: then convert column `Devices` to column which has only three values `Apple`, `Samsung` and `Others`. And later use it with `get_dummies`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I thought may be there is a parameter in  pd.get_dummies that would allow me to do it instead of manipulating my dataframe features

Comment: did you read documentation of `get_dummies` ? Did you find any features which could do this?

Comment: And all this "big speech" - beacuse people ask questions without checking documentation, without checking in Google, and without checking how to ask good question on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

data = {'name': ['Zoe', 'Yvonne', 'Veronique', 'Ruby', 'Mia', 'Matilda', 'Karin', 'Ella', 'Babette', 'Amelia'],
        'phone': ['Apple', 'Samsung', 'Samsung', 'HTC', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Nokia', 'Samsung', 'Motorola', 'Alcatel'],
        'car': ['Bentley', 'Bugatti', 'Ford', 'Hummer', 'Honda', 'Jaguar', 'Jeep', 'Lamborghini', 'Landrover', 'Pagani']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Let's say this is a part of the data:

```
    name        phone       car

0   Zoe         Apple       Bentley
1   Yvonne      Samsung     Bugatti
2   Veronique   Samsung     Ford
3   Ruby        HTC         Hummer
4   Mia         Apple       Honda
5   Matilda     Apple       Jaguar
6   Karin       Nokia       Jeep
7   Ella        Samsung     Lamborghini
8   Babette     Motorola    Landrover
9   Amelia      Alcatel     Pagani
```

First, recategorize the phone data:

```
aux = df['phone'].apply(lambda x: x if x in ('Apple', 'Samsung') else 'Other')
```

Next, apply `get_dummies`:

```
cat = pd.get_dummies(aux)
```

Finally, concatenate the dataframes and re-arrange the columns:

```
result = pd.concat([df,cat], axis=1)[['name', 'phone', 'Apple', 'Samsung', 'Other', 'car']]
result
```

to get this result:

```
    name       phone    Apple   Samsung Other   car

0   Zoe        Apple    1       0       0       Bentley
1   Yvonne     Samsung  0       1       0       Bugatti
2   Veronique  Samsung  0       1       0       Ford
3   Ruby       HTC      0       0       1       Hummer
4   Mia        Apple    1       0       0       Honda
5   Matilda    Apple    1       0       0       Jaguar
6   Karin      Nokia    0       0       1       Jeep
7   Ella       Samsung  0       1       0       Lamborghini
8   Babette    Motorola 0       0       1       Landrover
9   Amelia     Alcatel  0       0       1       Pagani
```

Comment: Thank you @lenka_cizkova, this exactly what I wanted